# How to read "<somestring>" in input string in perl

Tags: string, perl

Below is my code. It still produces same string with no "`<init>`"
  input string :

```
1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
```

```
  my $file = "Hello.javap";
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open '$file' $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {

       if (index(uc($line), uc("Code:")) != -1) {
        $code_block_started=1;
        }
        if(index($line,":")==-1)
        {
          if (my ($method) = $line =~ /.* \/\/ Method (.*);/) {
        print "Method: $method\n";
    }
          print $line;
          $code_block_started=0;
        }
        if($code_block_started){
        if ($line =~/[0-9]/) {
        my @num_strip = split(':',$line);
        my @get_command = split(' ',$num_strip[1]);
       # print "\n $get_command[0]";
        $count{$get_command[0]}++;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Also, you need to be clearer about the problem (What is the code suppose to do? What are you getting? What do you expect to get?)

Comment: Hello.javap file contains lines like below. i want to extract method name for "invokespecial" i.e. everything after word "Method" till "V". Below are contents of Hello.javap which i'm reading in my code.

Compiled from "Hello.java"
public class Hello {
  public Hello();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

Comment: We know. That doesn't address either issue I raised.

Comment: Hold on. let me edit the main post to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks..Problem solved...i modified my regex.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply asking how to escape the `"` in perl?  If so, write `\"<init>\"` just like in most languages.

Are you asking for a regular expression?  If so, `$str ~= /.* \/\/ Method (.*);/` will put `java/lang/Object."<init>":()V` into `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (my $str = <>) {
   if (my ($method) = $str =~ m{// Method (.*)}) {
      print "$method\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to read this input from javap file. There how to use \".

Comment: You don't. `"...\"..."` produces the string `..."...`, just like reading from a file would.

Answer (score 0):

> when Perl sees the double-quote just before the word "name" it thinks that was the end of the string and then it complains about the word name being a bareword.
>
> You might have already guessed, we need to escape the embedded " character:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $name = 'foo';
print "The \"name\" is \"$name\"\n";
```

http://perlmaven.com/quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings-in-perl